# "Booting in Insecure Mode" message after 8/28/2017 GRUB2 update

Tags: grub2, uefi, secure-boot

I have a dual boot 64 bit UEFI PC with Secure Boot turned off.

After today's GRUB2 update I get a "Booting in Insecure Mode" message before the GRUB2 screen appears.  This message was not annunciated prior to this update.

How can I get rid of the superfluous message?

Comment: How did you disable Secure Boot?

Comment: I disabled it in the UEFI settings, long ago.

Comment: Check if it is still disabled. There are 2 ways. One is to use mokutil, then you get this message. It is shown by the BIOS. The other is to disable in BIOS, then you shouldn't get this message.

Comment: I will check, but I'm 99.9% sure I disabled it in the BIOS because I was getting this message because of a prior GRUB/mok update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The Easy Response

This message is displayed by the Shim (`shimx64.efi`) program as a way to tell you that the computer is booting with Secure Boot unavailable or disabled. It is *not* an error message and it does *not* indicate a problem -- unless of course you thought you were booting with Secure Boot enabled, which is presumably why the message is displayed in the first place.

The saying "if it ain't broke, don't fix it" applies in this case. Nothing is broken. At worst, it's a superfluous boot message that you can safely ignore. You can do so and nothing bad will happen. This is the safest and easiest approach to dealing with what is, fundamentally, *not* a problem.

### If You Really Must Change It

If you're seriously annoyed by the message, you can remove it by bypassing Shim and booting GRUB directly. Be aware, though, that doing so means you will not be able to enable Secure Boot, should you decide you want to use it -- at least, not without reconfiguring the computer to boot through Shim. There's also a smallish risk of creating new problems, up to and including rendering your computer unbootable.

To bypass Shim, you must use the `efibootmgr` tool, or something equivalent in another OS. The procedure is:

1. Boot to Ubuntu
2. Open a Terminal window.
3. Type `sudo efibootmgr -v`. This will show you all your current boot entries. One of them will be called `ubuntu` and will reference `shimx64.efi`. There *may* be a second `ubuntu` entry that references `grubx64.efi`.
4. If you see a second boot entry that references `grubx64.efi`, you can change the `BootOrder` line by using the `-o` option to `efibootmgr`. This option sets a new boot order. Note the number of the `grubx64.efi` entry and pass it as the *first* option to `-o`, with the existing `BootOrder` entries filling out the rest. For instance, if your current `BootOrder` is `0007,000A,0000,0003` and the `grubx64.efi` entry is `Boot0003`, you'd type `sudo efibootmgr -o 0003,0007,000A,0000`.
5. If, OTOH, there is no existing `grubx64.efi` entry, you must create a new one with a command like `sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 2 -l \\EFI\\ubuntu\\grubx64.efi -L ubuntu`, but change `/dev/sda` to the disk device on which your [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) resides and change `2` (of `-p 2`) to refer to the ESP's partition number. Typing `df /boot/efi` will show you where your ESP is.
6. Reboot and hope it works.

Note that it's possible for the preceding procedure to render your computer *unbootable,* particularly if you need to create a new boot entry -- a typo can create an invalid entry, which will be ignored at best or lead to a boot failure at worst. This outcome isn't very likely, but you shouldn't dismiss the possibility entirely.

If this procedure confuses you, or if the risk of rendering your computer unbootable concerns you, please re-read the earlier part of my answer and reconsider making this change.

Note that the same task can be achieved in some computers' firmware (but the user interface varies), in an EFI shell by using its `bcfg` command, or in Windows by using the third-party [EasyUEFI](http://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html) tool. If you're dual-booting with Windows, this last option is likely to be much easier than using `efibootmgr` in Ubuntu -- at least, *if* there's an existing direct-boot option for GRUB. If not, then adding such an option won't be much easier or safer using EasyUEFI than using `efibootmgr`.

Comment: Thank you. Great answer, as always.  I'll live with the message.